# PowerShell Select-String from file with Regex

Tags: regex, string, powershell, substring

I am trying to get a string of text from a .sln (Visual Studio solution file) to show what project files are contained within the solution.

An example line of text is

> Project("{xxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xx}") = "partofname.Genesis.Printing", "Production\partofname.Genesis.Printing\partofname.Genesis.Printing.csproj", "{xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxxx}"
>   EndProject

The part of the string that I am interested in is the last part between the `\` and the `"`.

\partofname.Genesis.Printing.csproj"

The regular expression I am using is:

```
$r = [regex] "^[\\]{1}([A-Za-z.]*)[\""]{1}$"
```

I am reading the file content with:

```
$sln = gci .\Product\solutionName.sln
```

I don't know what to put in my string-select statement.

I am very new to PowerShell and would appreciate any and all help...

I did have a very very long-hand way of doing this earlier, but I have lost the work... Essentially it was doing this for each line in a file:

```
Select-String $sln -pattern 'proj"' | ? {$_.split()}
```

But a regular expression would be a lot easier (I hope).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The following gets everything between `"` and `proj"`:

```
Select-String -Path $PathToSolutionFile ', "([^\\]*?\\)*([^\.]*\..*proj)"' -AllMatches | Foreach-Object {$_.Matches} | 
       Foreach-Object {$_.Groups[2].Value}
```

The first group gets the folder that the proj file is in. The second group gets just was you requested (the project file name). `AllMatches` returns every match, not just the first. After that it's just a matter of looping through each collection of matches on the match objects and getting the value of the second group in the match.

Comment: I get `partofname.Genesis.Printing\partofname.Genesis.Printing.csproj` and not `Production\partofname.Genesis.Printing\partofname.Genesis.Printing.csproj` that I expected which is the part between " and proj". Can you explain what the corner brackets do, are they quantifiers? `^` means `not` and `?` is zero or one.`.` is any char and `*` is zero or more.

Comment: @Timo the second group doesn't get everything in the quotes. It only gets the project file name. But there was actually an error in the expression. The second `?` should have been a `+` or `*`. Various online resources can explain the regex components much better than I can in a comment.

Answer (score 7):

Your Script works great. To make into a one liner add -Path on the Select String:

```
Select-String -path $pathtoSolutionFile ', "([^\\]*?\\)?([^\.]*\..*proj)"' -
AllMatches | Foreach-Object {$_.Matches} | Foreach-Object {$_.Groups[2].Value}
```

To build from this you can  use Groups[0]

```
(((Select-String -path $pathtoSoultionFile ', "([^\\]*?\\)?([^\.]*\..*proj)"' -AllMatches | Foreach-Object {$_.Matches} | 
       Foreach-Object {$_.Groups[0].Value})-replace ', "','.\').trim('"'))
```

Comment: "_To make into a one liner_" confused me briefly (who hadn't made it a one-liner?) until I discovered [the accepted answer was edited to match this one after this answer was posted](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/26891936/revisions). Nbd, but makes more sense now.

Answer (score 1):

For me this pattern was the best:
`[^"]+\.csproj`